# How can it redirect SharePoint list Edit bottom when they click Stop button

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a SharePoint list containing items. If I click edit button, It will open the datasheet view and add item. And click the “stop ” button I come back to the list again.

How can I be redirected to a specific sharepoint site/page (i.e. Home) after I clicked the “stop ” button. Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

This is a novel approach I developed to get more flexibility and stability for the redirection behavior. It allows to set the redirection on the client side.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var button = $("input[id$=SaveItem]");
    // change redirection behavior
        button.removeAttr("onclick");
        button.click(function() {
            var elementName = $(this).attr("name");
            var aspForm = $("form[name=aspnetForm]");
            var oldPostbackUrl = aspForm.get(0).action;
            var currentSourceValue = GetUrlKeyValue("Source", true, oldPostbackUrl);
            var newPostbackUrl = oldPostbackUrl.replace(currentSourceValue, "MyRedirectionDestination.aspx");

            if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;
            WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(elementName, "", true, "", newPostbackUrl, false, true));
        });

});
```

Comment: Where can I put this script ? NewForm.Aspx or other ?

Comment: Suresh Answer this question ! Somewhere